# How to connect Datagrip on Ubuntu (WSL) inside Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu ecosystem from Microsoft Store (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0).

After setting up the environment, I installed postgres, which looks ok:

```
eliya@DESKTOP-LDD0TT1:/mnt/c/Users/Eliya$ sudo -i -u postgres
[sudo] password for eliya:
postgres@DESKTOP-LDD0TT1:~$ psql
psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Now, I have on my Windows Datagrip, and I can't figure out how can I connect to psql in my Ubuntu. First I tried to use `localhost` as my host, but it uses, of course, Windows `psql` service instead of ubuntu's.

How can I connect Datagrip to my virtual Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

To connect to datagrip you need enable connection by TCP/IP to postgres database . To enable that open `/etc/postgres/../postgresql.conf` and change the line:`#listen_addreses = ""` to `listen_addreses = "*"` (remove #, and put * symbol) and save it.
Then open `pg_hba.conf` (that is located in the same path that contains `postgresql.conf`) WITH sudo and the end of file add next lines to allow all connections (be careful):

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0               md5
```

Save it and restart the service: `sudo service postgresql restart`.
Finally, run `netstat -t` and copy the localaddress(not the foreign address), example: 172.17.125.13 BUT WITHOUT the port, because you will use the port of postgres database.

Finally use the IP copied in datagrip with the info of database such as username, password, port and database.

Be careful with the port of database that you use, because if you are running postgres on Windows the port 5342 is busy, and you get an error. If it occurs you need use another port, for example 5433 in WSL that you can modify in `postgres.conf` in the line to mention the port 5432 by default.

Hope this can help you!!

Answer (score 0):

In DataGrip you need to select `File` -> `New` -> `Data Source`:

[image]

Then select `PostgreSQL`:

[image]

Then enter in the appropriate host, user, password and database:

[image]